# modify existing iPhone camera screen

Tags: iphone, ios, photoshop

All I want is redesign default camera screen. Default camera screen has toolBar on bottom of the screen. and toolBar has capture button in middle and cancel button in left.

cancel button on left down corner should be replace with info button custom Image and right down corner should have photo library button. And All other functionality will be remain same.

How Can i achieve this without fully customization using overlay propery ?? Will This design be approve by apple ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify other apps in the phone. If you want to make your own camera app, do so. UIImagePickerController is the place to start:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Comment: I have an requirement to capture image using camera within App. but the design is very similar to default iPhone camera layout. they have added some extra button on the camera screen for example - cancel button(shows on toolBar) is replaced with info button. will those kind of design approve by apple ??

Comment: Yes, it's designed for you to customise it as much or as little as you need.